# Unable get value of all columns from CSV using OLEDB

Tags: c#, csv, oledb, .net-4.5

I am using OLEDB to parse CSV file into DataTable. It is working fine but it creates an issue when some value in CSV contains double quote("). OLEDB skips the value of the of the next remaining columns in that row.

For example, I have following values in CSV file. Here value of **Col2** in second row contain the double quote(").

[image]

When I parse the CSV to DataTable then DataTable contains the following values. Here the value of **col3** and **col4** in blank in the second row.

[image]

I am using following connection string

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ColNameHeader=True;CharacterSet=65001;FMT=Delimited(,)'"
```

And query is

```
"select * from [" + fileName + "]"
```

Here is the full code

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ColNameHeader=True;CharacterSet=65001;FMT=Delimited(,)'";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    table = new DataTable();
    var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + fileName + "]", conn);
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
}
```

How can I ignore double quote(") from value?

> Note: I am downloading the file from the third party directly use that this CSV for parsing.

Comment: it is in the visualbasic namespace, but certainly usable from c#. there is a class called TextFieldParser that makes processing CSVs easy. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx maybe try this instead of oledb?

Comment: @Jeremy - Will it work for file size > 300MB?

Comment: Its constructor is off of a standard .NET stream object, so you can use whatever streaming strategy works best in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You going to need to create schema.ini file and place it in the same directory as the files you're pulling the data from. In it you will have to give `TextDelimiter` and `Format` to the csv file. Set the `TextDelimiter` to `none`

```
[YOURCSVFILENAME.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
TextDelimiter=none
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**
Creating schema.ini file dynamically...

```
  string csvFilePath = /* CSV file directory */
  string csvFileName = /* CSV file name */
  using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(csvFilePath + "\\schema.ini", 
      FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) 
  { 
      using (StreamWriter writer=new StreamWriter(sr)) 
      { 
          writer.WriteLine("[" + csvFileName + "]"); 
          writer.WriteLine("ColNameHeader=True"); 
          writer.WriteLine("Format=CSVDelimited"); 
          writer.WriteLine("TextDelimiter=none"); 
          writer.Close(); 
          writer.Dispose(); 
      } 
  }
```

Comment: The CSV file name is dynamic. CSV file name is based on the current date. So how can I provide a dynamic file name in schema file?

Comment: And also I am reading multiple CSV files with the different format from a single folder.

Comment: In that case, you will have to create the schema.ini file dynamically before your open connection and query. See update above for sample code.